# Is .SetPassword secure

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following code to update multiple administrator passwords on managed computers. I have looked up documentation, but I cannot determine if the .setpassword command is secure over the network. Is it encrypted in any fashion?

I've heard mention that Powershell sometimes encrypts commands using the network credentials of the logged-in user, but I cannot verify that.

```
foreach($computer in Get-Content "hosts.txt") {
>> $adminUser = [ADSI] "WinNT://$computer/Administrator"
>> $adminpassword = ...
>> Write-Output $computer
>> Write-Output $adminpassword
>> $adminUser.SetPassword($adminpassword)
>> }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe. I wish could say yes or no. It depends. [grin]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsuser-setpassword

> The LDAP provider for Active Directory uses one of three processes to
> set the password; third-party LDAP directories such as iPlanet do not
> use this password authentication process. The method may vary
> according to the network configuration. Attempts to set the password
> occur in the following order:
>
> First, the LDAP provider attempts to use LDAP over a 128-bit SSL
> connection. For LDAP SSL to operate successfully, the LDAP server must
> have the appropriate server authentication certificate installed and
> the clients running the ADSI code must trust the authority that issued
> those certificates. Both the server and the client must support
> 128-bit encryption. Second, if the SSL connection is unsuccessful, the
> LDAP provider attempts to use Kerberos. Third, if Kerberos is
> unsuccessful, the LDAP provider attempts a NetUserSetInfo API call. In
> previous releases, ADSI called NetUserSetInfo in the security context
> in which the thread was running, and not the security context
> specified in the call to IADsOpenDSObject::OpenDSObject or
> ADsOpenObject. In later releases, this was changed so that the ADSI
> LDAP provider would impersonate the user specified in the OpenDSObject
> call when it calls NetUserSetInfo. In Active Directory, the caller
> must have the Reset Password extended control access right to set the
> password with this method

Comment: According to these three possibilties, the system is at least "designed" to be secure. As almost every software is in need of security patches on a regular basis, you can never tell if it actually is secure right now.